# Error while calling External REST URL from netsuite using token

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am not getting valid json response while calling 3rd party REST GET URL from netsuite . The 3rd party api is using oAuth2 , so i am passing the bearer token like this in the UserEvent Script . Can someone please tell what is wrong with this code .Below is the code snippet.

```
var sURL = "REST URL";

var header = { "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjb21wYW55X2lkIjoiYXBpdXNlck1ITVUiLCJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJhcGl1c2VyIiwic2NvcGUiOlsiYWNjdF9wYXlhYmxlIl0sImV4cCI6MTU0MzcxOTY3NCwiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9VU0VSIl0sImp0aSI6IjU4MjA2YTRkLTRhYTgtNDNjNy1iZTY2LWM2YTQ1NTg0YTY2ZSIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6Im5ldHN1aXRlLWNsaWVudCJ9.dPuwIpzZW3VrhkJnF_HaaNe8t4AMQ84UgMY5ZOK6j7g", 
                        "Content-Length": "0", 
                        "Content-Type": "application/json" };

        var request = https.get({
            url: sURL,
            headers: header
        });

        log.debug('req',request);
```

Getting below output in debugger:

{"type":"http.ClientResponse","code":406,"headers":{"X-Content-Type-Options":"nosniff","Pragma":"no-cache","Date":"Sat, 01 Dec 2018 23:46:46 GMT","Via":"1.1 mono00001.svale.netledger.com","X-Frame-Options":"DENY","Cache-Control":"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate","Set-Cookie":"JSESSIONID=4E42866C0A8D2D8504581B74C8D6FC1C; Path=/; HttpOnly","Expires":"0","Content-Length":"806","X-XSS-Protection":"1; mode=block","Content-Language":"en","Content-Type":"text/html;charset=utf-8"},"body":"HTTP Status 406 – Not Acceptableh1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}

## HTTP Status 406 – Not Acceptable

"
}

Comment: Calling the url in postman by passing bearer token is giving correct json response .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetSuite does not support oauth2.

Comment: Hi Eric. Can you tell if oauth1 is supported by Netsuite for this scenario? Because there is public bundle called "Veem" ,after installing it if we click a button in netsuite, then it will redirect to a 3rd party application for token based authentication.Further requests will use this generated token . My scenario above is similar to this, So i am in assumption that oauth is supported .

Comment: Adding one more point for better understanding. In above code i am just passing the bearer token and not mentioned any type as oAuth. In postman while testing URL i gave  type as "Bearer token" and passed the token, then it gave a valid reponse. Not sure why when called from code giving me Status code 406. My guess is it is something related to content type

Comment: oauth 1.0 is supported, yes.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem but this header solve the problem

*var header = {"Accept": "*/*", 
 "Content-Type":"application/json",
 "Authorization": accessToken
 }*

Comment: This was really helpful for me. 
Essentially, the error I was getting from external call made me think that Content-Type header was causing issues. In fact it needed the Accept header changing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept. 
Examining the response then showed that Accept could be set to 'application/json'. I'm not sure it would cause issues to have it wildcarded as it is above, but seems cleaner to have specific 'accept' type.
However, as a debugging tool, it saved my day, thank you